# Transform Lambert 2008 to GPS (EPSG:4326) in javascript

Tags: wgs84, lambert-conformal-conic

I'm a basic programmer and would like to transform Lambert 2008 coördinates (EPSG:3812) to GPS (EPSG:4326 or WGS84). I prefer having a formula to do this, because then I can implement it in JavaScript.

I already found this formula to go from Lambert to polar coordinates:

```
   x=150000+r*sin(theta)
   y=5400000-r*cos(theta)
```

But now I'm stuck, I don't know how to transform this.

Comment: And why not use one of existing JS libraries to do that for you?

Comment: @TomazicM I'm trying with proj4js library now. But do you know the string of Lambert 2008 for 'fromProjection' , I'm having difficulties finding it. (src https://www.npmjs.com/package/proj4)

Comment: See https://epsg.io/3812. Proj4js string for `EPSG:3812` projection is `"+proj=lcc +lat_1=49.83333333333334 +lat_2=51.16666666666666 +lat_0=50.797815 +lon_0=4.359215833333333 +x_0=649328 +y_0=665262 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"`.